# Finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: android

I had this problem for some hours, i did not risolve. please help me.

1. I have already did Clean / Build / Rebuild / Cache Invalidate /
   Gradle sync etc.
2. Finally i get this error when i have onClick Listner in Alert Dialog.
3. I am calling a button to show up a dialog from a fragment where i pass Context as "getActivity" .. But it works with Toast so
   it is not a problem(Toast works and Dialog also works with ok button
   with no listeners.)

> :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:checkDebugManifest
>       :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72220Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2220Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72200Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42220Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidAnswers132Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidBeta113Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlytics252Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlyticsCore235Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGithubLzyzsdCircleprogress110Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices750Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds750Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics750Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing750Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite750Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate750Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase750Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast750Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive750Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness750Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames750Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm750Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity750Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation750Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps750Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby750Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama750Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus750Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet750Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet750Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable750Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComJourneyappsZxingAndroidEmbedded303Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComOguzdevCircularFloatingActionMenu102Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareComReginaldSwiperefreshLibrary111Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareIoFabricSdkAndroidFabric136Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareRuNotiesScrollable113Library UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareDebugDependencies
>       :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug
>       :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:generateDebugResources
>       :app:mergeDebugResources
>       :app:processDebugResources
>       :app:generateDebugSources
>       :app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
>       :app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:processDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:compileDebugJava
>       Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>       Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>       :app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:compileDebugSources
>       :app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
>       :app:dexDebug
>
> UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
>         at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
>         at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
>         at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
>         at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
>         at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
>         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
>         at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>       Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>       com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 2
>       Information:BUILD FAILED
>       Information:Total time: 13.67 secs
>       Information:1 error
>       Information:0 warnings
>       Information:See complete output in console
>       **It was the Error**
>       Here is my Dialog and XML Button

**XML  for Button**

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Rimuovi chiamata abbinata"
    android:id="@+id/btn_del_chiamata"
    android:layout_above="@+id/riep_tec_rl_nav"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/delete"
    android:background="@xml/edit_text" />
```

Comment: what is your problem? it is crashing or not working?

Comment: TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException

Comment: The problem is multi dex files either you have imported a library twice or you are exceeding the libraries limit ! i can see are you really need to compile all play services libraries ? check this link for more understanding https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Answer (score 0):

You run into the 65K method count limit. Either you use multidex or reduce the number of methods ( e.g. with proguard ) Please read this: https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: I am using this compile for play services.  '    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'   But my application is an enterprise app so i do not use even play store to launch my application instead i use Twitter Fabrics.io. Also i use google map only. So i can i omit the google play services in Gradle?

Comment: **thanks for the reply i have cut off un used play service libraries, then it works.**